# Apache Server Configuration w/ Subdomain on AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am trying to configure an EC2 web server along with a domain named configured on Route 53 in AWS, but I am having trouble with getting subdomain working correctly. I can get to the server fine, just can't get the the subdomains.

The domain is hosted on GoDaddy, I've updated the name servers on GoDaddy to match the ones on AWS Route 53. When I try to go to example.com, it will arrive on my index page for the default virtualhost, but when I go to dev.example.com, it will also take me to the default virtualhost.

Here are some information regarding the setup:

**EC2 Server IP:** 10.10.10.1

**Elastic IP:** 1.1.1.1 (associated to network interface)

**Domain Name:** example.com

**Route 53 DNS Configuration**

```
example.com.        NS  (aws pre-configured)
example.com.        SOA (aws pre-configured)
example.com.        A   1.1.1.1
www.example.com.    A   1.1.1.1
dev.example.com.    A   1.1.1.1
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   dev.localhost localhost
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default** (yes, they are symlink to sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    ServerName localhost
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev** (yes, they are symlink to sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
    ServerName dev.localhost
    ServerAlias dev
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the actual host name in ServerName.

So instead of

```
ServerName localhost 
...
ServerName dev.localhost
```

You need

```
ServerName example.com
...
ServerName dev.example.com
```

The first one is handling all requests because it is the default, and the default server handles anything that doesn't match a ServerName.

Comment: I think I've also tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I've also added example.com and dev.example.com to the /etc/hosts file too.

Comment: ok weird, I tried that the first time but it didn't work, but it worked this time. Thanks a lot